# изменение сцены при нажатии на Button в Swing

Tags: java, swing

пишу игру с использованием Swing. В главном меню есть три кнопки(Jbutton).Необходимо при нажатии кнопки "Старт" соответсвенно запустить игру...какие образом это правильнее будет сделать?скрыть один frame и заменить на другой, или же с Panel что-то мудрить? подскажите как лучше,проще и правильнее...и немного не по этой теме вопрос: подкиньте толковые ссылки или может книжки по стилизации Jbutton(стандартный вид не очень хочется оставлять=) )

Comment: Зачем заменять один фрейм на другой? Нужно использовать метод paintComponent() и соответственно отрисовывать либо меню,либо саму игру в одном фрейме

Comment: @SlandShow , я и не знаю,как это сделать, поэтому и спрашиваю,буду очень признателен за ссылку с хорошим примером или непосредственно сам пример

Comment: Я могу кинуть ссылку на одного человека,который специально создал ресурс для начинающих игроделов  

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3BuJcKoljU&list=PL-2t7SM0vDffoasICG7X_6SObAW9L7hph

Comment: @SlandShow , к сожалению там ответа на интересующий вопрос.У него игра сразу начинается с главной сцены

Comment: Окей,тогда вот это  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dzhgsVaiSo&list=PL-2t7SM0vDfcIedoMIghzzgQqZq45jYGv

Comment: @SlandShow ,а это я уже все 8 видео посмотрел=) там одна панель и и картинка, которая при перерисовывании перекрывает предыдущие состояния и если ее убрать,то там все понакладывается друг на друга=(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необязательно заменять один фрейм на другой. Вы можете, например, удалять элементы из фрейма, а затем добавлять новые. Убрали панель для меню, а добавили панель для игры. Только не забывайте использовать repaint() и revalidate() после добавления/удаления элементов.

Для стилизации кнопки нужно наследовать кнопку от JButton и далее в методе paintComponent() делать непосредственно стилизацию. Думаю, что в интернете вы найдёте миллионы примеров. Код можете посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303379/java-jbutton-styling).